# Freezing first column of JQgrid grouping table

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I know that JQGrid doesn't support column freezing for grouping tables. But is there a customized JQGrid API to freeze the first column of JQGrid grouping table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any simple way to implement freezing column together with grouping. When you call `setFrozenColumns` new "frozen body" `<div>` will be created *over* the body of the grid. jqGrid makes copy of the body of the grid in the div. The table with first frozen column will be copied from the main grid body in the table in the "frozen body" `<div>`. One can see for example `+` icon in the grouping header. In case of supporting of frozen columns one need to create the same icon on the "frozen body". The original icon will be not seen more till one calls `destroyFrozenColumns` method. The grouping header have grouping text which is *over the whole columns* of the grid. jqGrid uses `colspan` attribute in the cells of the header row. It could be not so simple to place in the "frozen body" so that text could be long and be over the whole rows. I suppose that the with on the header will be restricted to the width of the "frozen body".

I included the above comments just to describe that there are a lot of implementation details which need be solved if one would decide to implement freezing column together with grouping. I can repeat that I don't see any simple way to do this. One have to change many parts of the grouping module ([grid.grouping.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.grouping.js)) and probably the code of `setFrozenColumns` and `destroyFrozenColumns` to implement the requirement.

Comment: While I browse through, I noticed that JQgrid has added new kind of feature call Pivot Tables(http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). What is the difference between normal JQgrid & Pivot JQGrid? It seems freeze column option is possible in Pivot grid.

Comment: @JohnSolomon: `jqPivot` method of jqGrid uses the the standard jqGrid internally. The main difference is the following: `jqPivot` *parse input data*, makes some aggregations of data, creates `colModel` with some dynamic generated column names based on the data input. After all `jqPivot` creates the grid. So `jqPivot` method is something like "predecessor" to create grid based on **local** data (`datatype: "jsonstring"` are used). It can set data grouping and call `setGroupHeaders` or `setFrozenColumns` additionally depend on the input options which you specify.